# Ocultar Action Bar / Barra superior en NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en nativescript pero no consigo ocultar en ios y en android el ActionBar

en ios no aparece si no lo pongo pero en android aparece automaticamente, entonces tengo que ponerlo pero darle `height:0` para que no se vea, pero eso hace que se vea en ios

¿Cómo puedo hacer para quitarlo en ambos dispositivos?

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer (estando en angular) es inyectar en el constructor el page así `import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";` y después accedes al objeto `this.page.actionBarHidden = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Hay que agregar el atributo `actionBarHidden` con el parámetro `true` al elemento `Page` de la siguiente manera:

```
<Page class="page" actionBarHidden="true">
```

Ya no es necesario colocar el elemento `ActionBar` en el código de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 formas de ocultarlo :) , en el lado del codigo (js o ts) cuando recibes la pagina puedes pasarle a la pagina la propiedad `page.actionBarHidden = true;`

```
// Para mi ejemplo usare Typescript que es como enseño a TNS :-) 
// Si estas usando Angular, iria dentro de ngOnInit
import { NavigatedData, Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export function onNavigatingTo(args: NavigatedData) {
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
    // page.actionBar.navigationButton.visibility = Visibility.collapse;
}
```

La otra forma es declarar dentro de tu vista la propiedad `actionBarHidden="true"` , ejemplo de ello:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" actionBarHidden="true" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

</Page>
```

Y ya no tienes que declarar ningún ActionBar dentro.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

You can hide to ActionBar in nativescript with angular

```
import { Page } from "@nativescript/core/ui/page";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-your',
    templateUrl: './your.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent {

    constructor(private page: Page) {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Explica con mas detalle el porque de tu respuesta y como es que resuelve el problema, de lo contrario sera eliminada, date una una vuelta por [answer], traduce tu respuesta, estas en SO en Español.